# Visual Studio Code preview files in browser while using Live Share

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveedit

I recently started using Visual Studio Code. I heard from a friend that there is a function/extension that you can edit files at the same time (live editing). So we started using it to edit HTML files etc. It works great, but there is one issue.

I can´t manage to see the files as a website in my browser, and that is because the Live Share extension doesn´t download the files to my pc, so I wont be able to just click the ´Show in browser´ option.

I´ve searched for it on the internet and my results are extensions that will show a file as if it was in a browser within Visual Studio Code itself. But all of them don´t work because they can´t find the file, because it isn´t downloaded.

My question is if there is a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!